# Using function that is assigned to const

Tags: javascript, object

I've got a problem printing the name of the persons.

I tried any combination like `person1.printName()`, `printName(person1)`, and nothing works. Could you give me any advice?

```
const printName = function() {
       console.log(this.name);
    }
    
    const person1 = {
        name: 'Aaron Towels' 
    }
    
    const person2 = {
        name: 'Tom Clancy' 
    }
```

Comment: `printName.apply(person1)` or `printName.bind(person1)()` both calls the method with `this` pointing to the `person1` object.

Comment: Simply define `printName` as a property of the objects (add `print: printName` into objects), then you can call it like `person1.print()`, and `this` will refer to the correct object in `printName` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to pass the person as a parameter to your function:

```js
const printName = function(person) {
   console.log(person.name);
}

const person1 = {
    name: 'Aaron Towels' 
}

const person2 = {
    name: 'Tom Clancy' 
}

printName(person1);
printName(person2);
```

Comment: it does not work for me :/ I tried this option as well
edit. I'm sorry, I didn't see that you had edited the function, I didn't add that the exercise needs to be done without changing the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options:

1. Using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
const bound_p1 = printName.bind(person1);
bound_p1();
```

*or shorter syntax*

```
printName.bind(person2)();
```

```js
const printName = function() {  console.log(this.name); }
const person1 = {  name: 'Aaron Towels' };
const person2 = {  name: 'Tom Clancy' };

const bound_p1 = printName.bind(person1);
bound_p1();

printName.bind(person2)(); // shorter syntax
```

2. Add `print` property with value is `printName` method.

```js
const printName = function() {  console.log(this.name); }
const person1 = {  name: 'Aaron Towels', print: printName };
const person2 = {  name: 'Tom Clancy', print: printName };

person1.print();
person2.print();
```

3. Adjust the `printName` method by using [`Object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

```js
const printName = function({name}) {  console.log(name); }
const person1 = {  name: 'Aaron Towels' };
const person2 = {  name: 'Tom Clancy' };

printName(person1);
printName(person2);
```

In case that *" exercise needs to be done without changing the function"*, I would suggest that you can use option 1 to complete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @squall